# What does the idiom "heel to head" mean?

Tags: idioms

In Robert Charles Wilson's novel "Vortex" he writes:

```
In the morning I toured him through Vox Core, heel to head.
```

I know the saying "head over heels", but this one is new to me. What does it mean?

(Disclaimer: non-native speaker here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likely meaning is “from bottom to top”, with   *heel to head* being used as a variant of *[from head to heel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_%28A%29)* (ie, of Latin  *a capite ad calcem*), which is an older (and now less common) form of *[from head to toe](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/head+to+toe)* or *from head to foot*.

Comment: This meaning sounds reasonable. Same idiom exists in my mother tongue ("Von Kopf bis Fuß").